# Browser showing xml code insted of actual output

Tags: tomcat6, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We are developing a web application using

- Oracle ADF
- jDeveloper
- Tomcat

The application is running fine on Integrated WebLogic Server. But when we are trying to run this application in tomcat, browser showing xml code of index.jsf instead of actual output, as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:document title="index.jsf" id="d1">
        <af:form id="f1">
            <af:region value="#{bindings.loginflowdefinition1.regionModel}" id="r1"/>
        </af:form>
    </af:document>
</f:view>
```

Please help us.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the app deployed?

Comment: We developed the app using jdeveloper - Oracle ADF

Comment: I tried with a simple test.jsf file that contains "hello World" text. But is showing entire xml code instead only "hello World"

Comment: Have you configured the Tomact server for ADF, by deploying ADF essential libraries? You can not deploy/run application built in ADF directly on Tomcat

Comment: configuration means we have done the following things

Comment: configuration means while creating war file in jdeveloper we have made some required configurations and we pasted all required jars for Oracle ADF app in tomcat\lib folder.

Comment: Make sure you have setup the tomacat as specified in https://technology.amis.nl/2012/12/02/deploy-adf-essentials-app-on-tomcat-6-x/ and deployed your app as instructed in https://technology.amis.nl/2014/01/03/deploy-oracle-adf-essentials-web-application-on-tomcat/

Comment: Hello amishra, Thanks a lot for your help. I followed above two tutorials and successfully deployed our app on tomcat 6. We are getting correct output for .jsp pages and we are again getting xml code for .jsf pages.

Comment: And in catalina log file we are getting this warning ................. Feb 19, 2015 12:10:19 PM org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.skin.SkinFactoryImpl getSkin
WARNING: Can't find a skin that matches family fusionFx and renderkit org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.desktop, so we will use the simple skin

Comment: Hello amishra. We finally deployed our adf app onto tomcat. using the above post. Thank you.

Comment: amishra can you help with this error [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626607/oracle-adf-tomcat-6-x-mysql-5-5-java-lang-abstractmethoderror